# Can I connect to SQL from JavaScript MVC?

Tags: c#, java, javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I am populating a list of names that will be added to my Sql Database.  In this simple case, how do I send the information to SQL server without my page being refreshed?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addNewRow() { 
    $('#displayPropertyTable tr:last').after('<tr><td style="font-size:smaller;" class="name"></td><td style="font-size:smaller;" class="address"></td></tr>');
    var $tr = $('#displayPropertyTable tr:last');
    var propertyCondition = $('#txtPropAddress').val();
    if (propertyCondition != "") {
        $tr.find('.name').text($('#txtPropName').val());
        $tr.find('.address').text($('#txtPropAddress').val());        
    }
} 
</script>
...
<table id="displayPropertyTable" width= "100%">
<tr>
     <td style="font-size:smaller;" class="name"></td>
     <td style="font-size:smaller;" class="address"></td>
</tr>
</table>
...
<table>
<tr>
     <td><b>Name</b></td>
     <td colspan="2"><input id="txtPropName" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td><b>Address</b></td>
     <td colspan="2"><input id="txtPropAddress" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
...
<button onclick="addNewRow();">Add</button>
```

Comment: Ajax: ASP.NET MVC has great support for server-side services that can easily be called from client-side JavaScript (e.g. through JQuery).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using AJAX via JQuery's `getJSON()` is a method I use a lot. `getJSON()` is a wrapper for the `ajax()` method I believe.

Here's an example of JS Method that serializes the form data and does an ajax request passing the serialized data.

If successful in this case you can pass back a Json Object. In my example I simply pass back a string that says "Success". So you will see an alert box now displaying Success in it, for my simple example.

```
function addRowsViaAJAX() {

    var d = new Date(); // IE hack to prevent caching

    $.getJSON('/ControllerName/ActionName', { Data: $('#MyForm').serialize(), Date: d.getTime() }, function(data) {
        // callback on success
        alert(data);
    }, 'json');
}
```

In you controller here's an example of an Action to use for AJAX
Your data comes in serialized as a linear string so you will have to parse it, which is pretty easy. Then take the data and do your respective database logic. Then return a Json Object.

```
public virtual JsonResult ActionName(string data)
{
   // take the data and parse the linear stream... I like to use the FormCollection
   FormCollection collection = new FormCollection();

   foreach (string values in data.Split('&')){
     string[] value = values.Split('=');
     collection.Add(value[0], value[1]);
   }
   // Now do your database logic here
   return Json("Success");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap that table in a form and then use the AJAX POST to send back the data to a server side page that actually does the insert.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: [URL_TO_PAGE_THAT_DOES_DB_INSERT],
    data: $(_('[YOURFORMID')).serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
               //do something

    }
        error: function(xhr){
              //do something else
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with the .ajax method

```
var prop= {};

prop["Name"] = $("#txtPropName").val();
prop["Address"] = $("#txtPropAddress").val();

$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     url: "/Admin/AddProperty",
     data: JSON.stringify(release),
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(result) {
          // do something on success                      

     },
     error: function(result) {
         // do something on error 
     }  
 });
```

Then in your controller you could do this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult AddProperty(Property prop)
{
   // add property to database, etc.        
   return Json(true);
}
```

You can get JSON.stringify from [here](http://www.json.org/).